# Mutate between dates from external lookup table

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to mutate a `tibble` which contains a list of dates by looking up an external 'dates lookup table':

```
date_lookup<-tibble(start = lubridate::dmy("01012020", "01022020"),
           end = lubridate::dmy("31012020", "28022020"),
           id = c(1, 2))

df<-tibble(record = c("A", "B"),
           date = lubridate::dmy("15022020", "03012020"))
```

If a date in `df` is between a start or end date in `date_lookup` I want to pull across the appropriate `id` from `date_lookup`.

I have tried the following:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(id = ifelse(between(date, date_lookup$start, date_lookup$end), date_lookup$id, NA))
```

But as you can see, the first row in `df` is showing as `NA` (it should be showing the number 2).

Expected output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Rowwise: 
  record date          id
  <chr>  <date>     <dbl>
1 A      2020-02-15     2
2 B      2020-01-03     1
```

A `dplyr` solution would be preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fuzzyjoin` here :

```
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_inner_join(df, date_lookup, 
           by = c('date' = 'start', 'date' = 'end'), match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  record date       start      end           id
#  <chr>  <date>     <date>     <date>     <dbl>
#1 A      2020-02-15 2020-02-01 2020-02-28     2
#2 B      2020-01-03 2020-01-01 2020-01-31     1
```

---

Using `tidyverse` functions :

```
tidyr::crossing(df, date_lookup) %>% dplyr::filter(date >= start, date <= end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach which uses non-equi joins and then assigns the value to the original data.frame.

```r
library(data.table)
library(tibble)
date_lookup<-tibble(start = lubridate::dmy("01012020", "01022020"),
                    end = lubridate::dmy("31012020", "28022020"),
                    id = c(1, 2))

df<-tibble(record = c("A", "B"),
           date = lubridate::dmy("15022020", "03012020"))

setDT(date_lookup)
setDT(df)

df[date_lookup,
   on = .(date >= start,
          date <= end),
   id := id]

df
#>    record       date id
#> 1:      A 2020-02-15  2
#> 2:      B 2020-01-03  1
```