# assign new grouping variable based on time series interval from other dataframe

Tags: r

I'm a relative novice in R and am struggling with the following. I have one dataframe with a column of CO2 concentrations measured every second and a column with date-time (POSIXct), and a second dataframe with "start" and "stop" date-time. What I would like to do is assign a grouping variable (e.g. ascending numbers) in a new column to the dataframe with the CO2 concentrations based on the start/stop times of the second dataframe.

For example: start = 13:30 stop=13:33, so all the measured CO2 concentrations get grouping variable '1' if they fall in between the start/stop time.

As there is time between the first row of start/stop times and the second row, there are also many CO2 measurements which should get "NA" as the grouping variable.

Here is a subset of the start/stop data:

```
times <- structure(list(Start = structure(c(1591266360, 1591266960), class = c("POSIXct",  "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Stop = structure(c(1591266540, 1591267140 ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

And as the dataframe of the CO2 concentrations is rather large I've put the output in a text file:
[CO2 dataframe subset](https://app.box.com/s/qqr7w86m3emricabafzdhlkcut3azbcw).

This is the first time asking a question here (as most of my previous questions were already asked before), so I apologise in advance if things are unclear.

Comment: Here there is your solution: https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidy-way-to-range-join-tables-on-an-interval-of-dates/7881/2

Comment: This is similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/overlap-join-with-start-and-end-positions Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62912260/mutate-between-dates-from-external-lookup-table/

Comment: Ronak Shah, you're right! I was thinking in the wrong direction, which made my search unsuccessful. I did not master the art of searching yet I suppose (searched for hours), or I didn't recognize the solutions as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link I left you in the comments, here is your solution.

Your data:

```
times <- structure(list(Start = structure(c(1591266360, 1591266960), class = c("POSIXct",  "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Stop = structure(c(1591266540, 1591267140 ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
df <- eval(parse("df.text"))
```

Solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

# define a group per each row before joining
times <- times %>%
  mutate(group = row_number())


# fuzzy join! 
fuzzy_left_join(
  df, times,
  by = c("dt" = "Start", "dt" = "Stop"),
  match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`)  # here you specify what function to use for the join!
)
```

`fuzzyjoin` looks like a pretty cool package.
It allows you to do this kind of particular joins that `dplyr` lacks of.